# AVPlayerViewController - UIButton not triggering video

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, avplayerviewcontroller

I am using AVPlayerViewController in order to play a .mov file (TeethingFinal.mov) in my project.  The funny thing is, I have the feature working perfectly with two other buttons on the same ViewController but for some reason will not launch the AVPlayer!  The tap gesture is being recognized, because I can see the button highlight when pressed but nothing happens.  I would post error message but there is not one!

```
     @IBAction func sugarBugPlay(sender: UIButton) {
        let moviePlayerController = AVPlayerViewController()
        let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("TeethingFinal", ofType:"mov")
        let url = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(path!)
        let playerVC = AVPlayerViewController()
        var player: AVPlayer = AVPlayer()
        playerVC.player = AVPlayer(URL: url)
        self.presentViewController(playerVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

[image]

Comment: can you show us some code that does work (you mention other cases that proved to be successful) ?

Comment: The code above is the same code used for my other functional buttons, just replaced with button name.      

@IBAction func toothEruptPlay(sender: UIButton) {
        let moviePlayerController = AVPlayerViewController()
        let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("TeethingFinal", ofType:"mov")
        let url = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(path!)
        let playerVC = AVPlayerViewController()
        var player: AVPlayer = AVPlayer()
        playerVC.player = AVPlayer(URL: url)
        self.presentViewController(playerVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

Comment: Are you sure you have that file (correctly named) in your bundle ? I don't see anything wrong with your code, that's why it's puzzling me why the other cases seem to work and this one doesn't...

Comment: That's what is puzzling me as well.  I even changed the file name to the other video that works with other UIButton to test it, but that does not work either.  I checked the connection and all is right there too.

Comment: I guess you do, otherwise `NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(...)`would fail...

Comment: wild guess: could you try to make your `AVPlayerController` a property so that your controller has a strong reference to it ? so instead of declaring it in the function, move it outside and make it a property

Comment: this would especially be useful if you reuse the player, there is no need to recreate a player on each button press (if the buttons are all within the same controller and the videos are all shown in the same controller as well)

Comment: great idea, after testing, unfortunately no resolution.  I declared the AVPlayerController outside the button functions, the other two buttons still worked but not the UIButton in question!  Tap gesture still being recognized...

Comment: The only way I could help you out at this point is if you could give me access to your project in some way (not sure if you are ready to do that though... )

Comment: i appreciate the effort but legally i am unable to do that.

Comment: Alright, I guess it's on you then... I can't really think of any problems with your code especially if you made it work the other two times. My final suggestion would be to replace the file name in the function that is causing problems with a video url that you know works in the other functions. That way you can eliminate the fact that your url is faulty...

Comment: yes that was one of the alternative solutions i tried as well.  it is not a faulty URL....  I even cleaned the project, deleted derive data, quit Xcode, restarted computer, and reprogrammed the button and function - still nothing.  VERY strange.

Answer (score 0):

So sometimes Xcode is funny.  I created a completely new ViewController the exact same way and reattached all of my outlets and it worked!